# Body background color: multiple sideways and directions

Tags: html, css, background-color

I was trying to create a multiple sideways background color in multiple directions like [here](https://firebase.google.com/).

I was trying to work with `background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, white,white 80%,#000099,#000099 20%);` but this will create multiple css background color in one direction. What I really need is like firebase background.

Any hints? This is my trial:

```css
html {
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /*background-color: #f3f3f3;*/ 
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, white,white 80%,#000099,#000099 20%);
}
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: White; margin-top: 150px" class="container">
  test test
</div>
```

Comment: Firebase's background is just a vector image

Comment: Try to resize the webpage you will see that colors are changing, some of the disappear when it becomes too small

Comment: When you inspect the source, you'll see background consists of three `.svg` images

Comment: Ok I could find them now thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following code. Or tell me the colors to set as background color.

```css
html {
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /*background-color: #f3f3f3;*/ 
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#87e0fd+0,d84953+40,05abe0+100 */
  background: rgb(135,224,253); /* Old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(135,224,253,1) 0%, rgba(216,73,83,1) 40%, rgba(5,171,224,1) 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(135,224,253,1) 0%, rgba(216,73,83,1) 40%, rgba(5,171,224,1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(135,224,253,1) 0%, rgba(216,73,83,1) 40%, rgba(5,171,224,1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(135,224,253,1) 0%, rgba(216,73,83,1) 40%, rgba(5,171,224,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */ /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */ /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#87e0fd', endColorstr='#05abe0',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: White; margin-top: 150px" class="container">
  test test
</div>
```

Comment: Colors are : #000099  #9900CC  and white; But in your example colors are not solid, they are fading into each others, neither multiple sideways and directions

Answer (score 0):

I used [repeating](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_repeating-linear-gradient.asp) option. Here is snippet:

```css
html
        {
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
        }
        body
        {
          background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(45deg,
   #9900CC,
   #9900CC 40%,
   #000099 40%,
   #000099 80%);
        }
```

```html
 <div style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: White; margin-top: 150px"
        class="container">
       
        test test
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but this is with one direction, my question was for multiple directions, is this possible ?